# What should an ISO-8601 date look like at exactly 0 milliseconds?

Tags: java, datetime, jackson, iso8601

I am calling a web service that formats dates using ISO-8601 (as far as I can tell).

Here is the pattern I am using the parse the dates (I'm using Jackson to de-serialize the response):

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

Most of the time, the service returns dates that look like this:

```
2022-08-19T22:48:17.228Z
```

However, the service occasionally returns a date like this:

```
2023-09-12T00:18:25Z
```

I think this occurs when the number of milliseconds is exactly 0.

Is this expected behavior for ISO-8601 dates, or is the service doing something weird?

Comment: I don't see an indication in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) that a normal Formatter will do this. Perhaps it's coded into the default Jackson serializer?

Comment: Jackson instantly makes me go "HEEEE hEEEEE"

Comment: Decimal fractions are, per the spec, entirely optional but must be "agreed upon" so wherever you're pulling this data from (if it's spec compliant) should have documentation about this behaviour somewhere. (even more fun, decimal fractions are allowed on "the smallest time" unit so half a minute could be `T00:01,5` and that would be an entirely valid time in an ISO-8601 date). So there's two possibilities: either Jackson is parsing things wrong (in which case, verify that with a small test app), or it's not and it's time to hunt down the API docs.

Comment: `Instant.parse()` parses both examples, with and without the decimals. I had expected jackson-modules-java8 to do the same, but if not, you can always write your own deserializer that uses the mentioned `Instant.pares()`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

> This profile does not specify how many digits may be used to represent
> the decimal fraction of a second. An adopting standard that permits
> fractions of a second must specify both the minimum number of digits
> (a number greater than or equal to one) and the maximum number of
> digits (the maximum may be stated to be "unlimited").

Meaning that the "mask" used by the service considers the 3rd digit of the milliseconds to be optional, and when it is 0 it will hide the value altogether.

A fix would be to check the length of the date and add a 0 before the last character (assuming its always Z)

Answer (score -1):

> *"... What should an ISO-8601 date look like at exactly 0 milliseconds? ..."*

You can utilize the *[Date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#%3Cinit%3E(long))* class, which has a *constructor method* for *milliseconds*.

```java
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
out.println(f.format(new Date(0)));
```

```
1969-12-31T19:00:00.000Z
```

> *"... the service occasionally returns a date like this:*
>
> ```
> 2023-09-12T00:18:25Z
> ```
>
> *I think this occurs when the number of milliseconds is exactly 0. ..."*

No, this is a valid date and time.
The hours are *0 – 23*, where *0* is *12 am*.

> *"... Is this expected behavior for ISO-8601 dates, or is the service doing something weird? ..."*

The blame would be on the service, the *ISO 8601* is just a notation, or code.